# If $A$ is a matrix with a row of zeros, then the product $AB$ also has a row of zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I know there is a similar question posted on this site, but it does not have a proof, and I would rather have my proof for the problem criticized than look at a proof as an answer on the other post.

Suppose that $A$ is an $m \times r$ matrix with a row of zeros in the $i$-th row and let $B$ be an arbitrary $r \times n$ matrix.

Denote the $i$-th row vector of $A$ as $\mathbf{a}_i = \mathbf{0}$ where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero row vector. Then the product $\mathbf{a}_i B$ is the $i$-th row vector of the matrix $AB$ denoted $(\mathbf{AB})_i$ By definition of matrix multiplication, we have

$$((\mathbf{AB})_i)_{ij} = (\mathbf{a}_i B)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^r a_{ik}b_{kj} = 0$$

for each $j = 1, \dotsc, n$.

Therefore,

$$(\mathbf{AB})_i = \mathbf{0}$$

so the matrix $AB$ has a row of zeros in the $i$-th row.

Comment: The proof looks fine, except that in the main equation, $i$ seems to represent two different things. One is the $i$th row of A, but the other is referring to an arbitrary row of $(\mathbf{AB})_i$. You could just drop this usage of $i$ as we know there is only one row, or replace it with another letter to avoid confusion

Comment: I believe you are referring to the two $i$'s in $((\mathbf{AB}_i)_{ij}$, which gave me pause when I wrote it, but I do not know another way to represent the arbitrary $ij$ entries in the $i$-th row vector. Any suggestions? Maybe introduce a different index?

Comment: Introducing a different index works just fine. Though in this case you could also just drop it

Comment: If we drop the outermost $i$ to make $(\mathbf(AB)_i)_j$, how is it clear that we are taking the $ij$ entries from $\mathbf{AB}_i$, which is an $i$-th row vector of $AB$, instead of the entries from the matrix $AB$, which is what $(\mathbf{AB}_i)_j$ seems to suggest? I think I'm missing something.....

Comment: The thing inside the $(\cdot)_j$ notation is not $AB$. Instead, the thing inside the $(\cdot)_j$ notation is $(AB)_i$, which is a different object. That is how you know that $(\cdot)_j$ is not just indexing directly into $AB$ somehow. A row vector should not need a row index, because there is no question about which row anything is in, and attempting to specify a row index for it only confuses things.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you mean. Thank you @DavidK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine. A minor comment is rather than using $((AB)_i)_{ij}$, why not just use $((AB)_i)_{j}$

Comment: Is it clear that $((AB)_i)_j$ are entries of the $i$-th row vector of $AB$? If it is, would you mind explaining to me how this is true? To me, it looks like such a notation may be referring to the entries in the matrix $AB$ as opposed to the row vector in question. But I'm pretty new to this, so I can't wait to learn more.

Comment: We use only one subscript when indexing a vector. We use two subscripts to index a matrix. So writing $((AB)_i)_{ij}$, using two subscripts $(\cdot)_{ij}$, makes it look (almost) like the pair of subscripts $ij$ are indexing the entries of $AB$ directly rather than indexing into a row vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose the problem, your question becomes the following : if the matrix $B$ has a column of zeros, then the matrix $AB$ as a column of zeros. If you translate this problem in terms of linear maps, the question becomes : if $f : V_1 \to V_2$ and $g : V_2 \to V_3$ are linear maps and $v \in V_1$ satisfies $f(v) = 0$, then $g(f(v)) = 0$. This is super mega trivial. All you have to do now is translate!

(Hint : you can do the "translation" by letting $V_1 = \mathbb R^n$, $V_2 = \mathbb R^r$, $V_3 = \mathbb R^m$ and let $v$ be one of the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^n$.)

P.S. Your proof sounds good to me. However, I hope that you are aware that writing $_{ij}$ as an index is not just an indicator that we are interested in a coefficient of the matrix but rather the coefficient in row $i$ and column $j$. Therefore writing $( (AB)_i)_{ij}$ should be technically written $((AB)_i)_{1j}$ if you consider it as a $1 \times n$ matrix, or $((AB)_i)_j$ if you consider it as a vector (i.e. not a $2$-dimensional array, but a one-dimensional one). My preference would be to fix $i$ (since we are studying the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and write $(AB)_{ij}$, which is much clearer.

Hope that helps,